# Artifactory HA s3-storage-v3 Permissions Issue

Tags: amazon-s3, artifactory

Using the latest helm chart `4.7.6`  and latest artifactory build `7.12.6` I've setup the backend using S3V3.

My `binarystore.xml` is configured as follows:

```
    <provider id="s3-storage-v3" type="s3-storage-v3">
        <testConnection>false</testConnection>
        <region>us-east-1</region>
        <bucketName>example-development-artifactory</bucketName>
        <path>artifactory/filestore</path>
        <endpoint>s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com</endpoint>
        <maxConnections>50</maxConnections>
        <useInstanceCredentials>true</useInstanceCredentials>
        <refreshCredentials>true</refreshCredentials>
        <roleName>arn:aws:iam::<redacted>:role/artifactory-k8s-s3-role</roleName>
        <usePresigning>false</usePresigning>
        <signatureExpirySeconds>300</signatureExpirySeconds>
        <kmsServerSideEncryptionKeyId>alias/development-artifactory-s3</kmsServerSideEncryptionKeyId>
        <property name="s3service.server-side-encryption" value="aws:kms"></property>
    </provider>
```

I had to manually edit this file to enter many of the values as the helm chart didn't seem to respect the override values I set.

In the Artifactory logs I'm getting the errors:

```
021-01-28T21:50:04.365Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [7b2ddbde9c2d661d] [.c.EventualDownstreamWorker:74] [-cluster-s3-worker-2] - EventualDownstreamWorker caught error while operating on actions for sha1 1f210f9518d447d88bcfe69956ae04a9eee5ef66:
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 9C984900E360C286; S3 Extended Request ID: 2VKwlNzoHrFAt3PF4ysuCzUEhh619NebawfUjAOJXNwrsd3wz/XqgFO63nGmfsR4DvuEIQ2zNWo=; Proxy: null)
```

There was an open issue on Github https://github.com/jfrog/charts/issues/839 but supposedly has been fixed.

Anyone know of a way I can test out why I'm getting these constant deny issues? Thanks!

Role Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It says forbidden when Artifactory is trying to upload a file to S3, and I suspect the problem here to be with the arn value in the rolename, just pass on the rolename as "artifactory-k8s-s3-role" and start the Artifactory. Also, check the bucket policy if it is blocking something. If possible share the bucket policy JSON

Comment: I updated the `binarystore.xml <roleName>` to just be "artifactory-k8s-s3-role" with the same error.

Updated Question w/ S3 Policy (it's wide open)

Comment: I figured out this is happening due to the Pod using the Worker Node IAM Role instead of the Role created & assigned to the Pod. I'm not sure how to get the Pod to use the correct role instead of inheriting it from the Node.